# Find all imperial units and replace with their metric counterparts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to go through a whole website looking for imperial units, e.g lbs, feet, inches and convert them to metrical values, kilos, meters, centimeters.

Example:

```
<main>
  <h1>Top speed of new car is 300mph/h</h1>
  <p>
    Such a fast car, previously going only 250 mph, now topping speeds up to 300mph.
    And it only weighs 300lbs, 20 pounds less than before!
  </p>
</main>
```

Becomes:

```
<main>
  <h1>Top speed of new car is 482.8km/h</h1>
  <p>
    Such a fast car, previously going only 402km/h, now topping speeds up to 482.8km/h.
    And it only weighs 136kg, 9kg less than before!
  </p>
</main>
```

The question isn't how to convert from mph/lbs to kmh/kg, but how to find and store values such as "10mph", "10 mph", "200lbs", "200 lbs", "200 pounds" in a good way, convert them and finally replacing them.

Any pointers would be very helpful!

**Edit** A simplified example of what I want to achieve:

```
<p>This is 10 lbs</p>
<p>This is 20lbs</p>

<script>
  $('p').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

    if(text.indexOf('lbs') >= 0) {
      // Store "XX lbs" in a variable
      // Wrap the above created variable in a <span>
      // Convert the variable to kg
      // Replace the text in <span> with the value in kilogram
      // Output: <p>This is <span>4.5kg</span></p>
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: I think we might get you started but a little code by you might be nice. So assuming that all of the text will be XXXlbs XXXpounds XXX, you'll read text with something like variablename = $('div').html(), then with js search for the units, search backward for the previous space, grab the numbers, do the conversion, and replace the text. Not a trivial pursuit.

Comment: How this question is related to Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: This is virtually impossible to do just by scanning natural text. Firstly, consider a unit measured in `m`. This could be meters, miles, or several others. Without knowing the context of the text, you have an unsolvable ambiguity. Secondly, many units can be written in several ways: `kph` and `km/h` are the same thing. Finally, 'imperial' units are not well defined: A British mile is different from a US mile. And other versions of 'mile' exist as well. The same applies to most other imperial units. Again, you would have to be certain of the context of the text before you even started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can start by building a mapping of units that should be converted from what to what and their conversion ratios:

```
var unitMapping = {
  mph : { unit : 'km/h', ratio : 1.609 }, // there is no such thing as mph/h ?  
  lbs : { unit : 'kg', ratio : 0.45 },
  pounds : { unit : 'kg', ratio : 0.45 }
};
```

Now you need to replace the text with the correct values. First create a regexp that matches all your units:

```
var regexp = new RegExp('(\\d*) ?(' + Object.keys(unitMapping).join('|') + ')', 'g');
```

Write a clever replace function that takes a non-standard unit and returns a standard one:

```
var replaceFunction = function(match, value, unit){
  return value*unitMapping[unit].ratio + unitMapping[unit].unit;
};
```

And finally bring it all together by taking the text and replacing it with the correct version:

```
var replaceNode = document.querySelector('main');
replaceNode.innerHTML = replaceNode.innerHTML.replace(regexp, replaceFunction);
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/UPEmEjuS/1/edit

As you can see, there is some repetition in unitMapping. The solution can obviously be improved by making the mapping depend on the normalized units, but i chose this option because it makes the code clearer for a SO post.

Comment: This doesn't work with fractions, or with numbers that use commas to separate myriads.  Perhaps `\d+` could be expanded upon and `replaceFunction` could do parsing on `value` instead of replying on the implicit string->number coercion done by the `*` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: [webpage-unit-conversion](https://code.google.com/p/webpage-unit-conversion/):

> JavaScript code that can be embedded in a page to convert units in the page between metric (SI) units and British Imperial/US units along with CSS that allows flexible choosing of which units are displayed.

There's a [demo](https://webpage-unit-conversion.googlecode.com/git/units.html) page that shows how it works.  It's got some biases, e.g. "degree" is assumed to refer to temperature instead of angle.